How to redirect URL to a subdomain except one folder that needs to go somewhere else
I'm trying to workout how to generate the correct code for my .htaccess
I found the following code
RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdir\.maindomain\.co.uk$
[NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://shop\.maindomain\.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

This works great to forward all requests to the folders on the subdomain, but I need the folder
www.maindomain.co.uk/oldshop
to be forwarded to shop.maindomain.co.uk NOT to shop.maindomain.co.uk/oldshop as it currently is using the above code.
I can't work out how to add this part - hope this makes sense, thanks for your help!
